# How application get update from apple store?

Tags: ios, cordova

I want to know about process of app update from apple store. I have below mentioned doubts about process:

1. Code base overwrite or just replace?
2. Does application re install and install during update process?
3. If suppose that application is running in device, take an update from apple store..now   user get same screen or application launch again??
4. I used phone gap for application. if suppose that application is running and user get update..at that time mew js file work or old??

Please share information about same with me. Actually, I submitted application in both environment iOS and Android, its working fine in both platform. after some time i have resubmitted update in both platform that is available at both Apple/Google store. When i update android app from Google market its working fine, but when i update app from apple store its not working fine ..simlpy hangs at login screen. when just install fresh build its working fine.

Could you please help on this?

Answer (score 3):

If an app is running when the system begins installing an update, the system kills the running app before installing.  The app will be launched the next time the user opens it.

When the system installs an app update, it deletes all files in the old version of the app bundle and then installs the files from the new version of the app bundle.  If any files existed in the old app bundle but not in the new app bundle, they are gone after the app has been updated.

The user's files (such as the contents of the app's Documents directory) are not touched.

If your app hangs after you have updated it, then you have a bug that you should try to track down in the debugger.

#### UPDATE

If the user manually uninstalls the app, the system removes all of the user's documents for that app, and removes the user's preferences, and removes any other files (like cache files) associated with the app.  So when the user uninstalls the old app before installing the new app, he is starting with a “clean slate”.

If the user just updates the app from the app store, without manually uninstalling the old version first, all of his existing documents and user preferences and cache files are still around.  If the new version of the app doesn't understand one of those files or preferences, it might crash.

As the app developer, it is **your responsibility** to make sure the new version of your app is compatible with the old versions of documents, user preferences, caches, or anything else that might be around after an upgrade.

Comment: Thanks Rob for helpful information. I am strange the same application is working fine when user uninstall old version build and install new version build. I also checked in local environment..its working fine.Do you have any idea on this????

Comment: Thanks Rob for valuable information. I have changed db script in new version and also add functionality to check if there is old db, delete it and create new db. Actually I used Phonegap technology which used HTML/Jquery file.I am familiar with Android application and new in iOS application. And I used same code base its working fine in android application during update.I understand its my responsibility, but i am unable to find root cause of it. Do you know any debug method that help me in local environment.???

Comment: I don't know anything special about debugging phonegap.

Comment: Thank you so much Rob for helping on this. Do you know how to test version upgrading scenario in our local environment??/

Answer (score 0):

I don't have any idea how PhoneGaps works but as far as I know for iOS, the code is replaced by the new version when you download it from AppStore or somewhere else (MAM/MDM) but saved content (such as user preferences) is not removed.

First the  user downloads the app from the store, then the code is replaced and finally iOS checks the validity of your certificates. If everything works well the new app is available.

There is no forced update, which means the user has to tap on the download button on the AppStore.

Comment: Thanks Geraud for useful information. I have been facing an issue, when user get update from apple store...and try to login into app it doesn't respond and its working fine when user try to login with fresh build(uninstall old build nad install new build).Do you have any idea regarding this issue???

Comment: Maybe it's due to a specific user settings? As I mentioned, they are kept when you upgrade the app. You can have a look at the NSDefault used in the previous version of the app.