# Why does Trigger.IO app need to be uninstalled when upgrading on iOS?

Tags: iphone, ios, webview, trigger.io

I'm testing a Trigger.IO app built with Forge v1.4 on an iPod running iOS 6. I've been installing the .ipa through a distribution provision profile.

Occasionally, after installing an updated version, the app would launch but not run correctly. I traced this behaviour to the `window.forge` being absent, presumably due to a bad initialization. I would then make sure to kill the app process before installing updates and my recollection is that this *seemed* to make the problem go away.

Now, I've added the Facebook and Splash modules and my app now consistently won't go past the splash screen after I install an upgraded version unless I forcibly uninstall the old version first. Presumably, it dies before creating the webview. Any idea why I would need to uninstall my app first before upgrading? Is this a known behaviour?

I want to make sure that my users don't experience this when upgrading.

My app runs happily without Forge, and doesn't have any particular dependencies on localStorage data. I don't have a Mac and have been installing via iTunes in Windows, so I don't think I can access logging information.

Comment: For logging, look at the iPhone configuration utility which runs on Windows. When you say it doesn't run correctly, do you mean the app hangs? Or crashes? I'd recommend delaying your initialisation JS until after DOMContentLoaded - see if that helps

Answer (score 2):

You should have a look at this post:
[How application get update from apple store?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12794252/how-application-get-update-from-apple-store/12794368#12794368)

The quick answer is when you update an app, you install the new bundle but you keep the user data stored previously such as a local DB. If you changed the local DB in the new app (or anything else) your app can crash when updated but is fine when downloaded from scratch.

Comment: Hi Geraud. Thanks for your answer.

I'm aware that user data persists between upgrades. I'm wondering if there may be an issue with Forge's own internal use of user data that would cause it to crash between app upgrades, since it appears to crash before initializing the webview.